# Change color of application bar

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview

For changing the view's background color, I've used the following code:

```
self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.mainColor().cgColor
```

But I would also love to change the color's of the application bar, which I suppose is the bar right above the window which has the three buttons (red, orange and green).

Comment: I don't even know what you so-call application bar is.

Comment: Do you mean the title bar of a window?